# Error is overlapping with the other elements and not taking up its own space

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have an Angular 11 project with a sign up form that shows errors when user's phone number format or length is not correct.

Problem is, `mat-error`s are not taking up their own space and are just showing on top of other elements like so:

[image: signup form]

Here's my `html`:

```
  <div class="mobile-number__container">
    <dropdown-autocomplete-countries
      id="countryTelephoneCode"
      caption="{{ 'auth.signup.choose_country' | localePipe }}"
      desiredValueKey="phoneCode"
      [control]="phoneVerificationFormControls.countryTelephoneCode"
    >
    </dropdown-autocomplete-countries>

    <mat-form-field id="mobileNumber" appearance="outline">
      <span matPrefix
        >+{{ phoneVerificationFormControls.countryTelephoneCode.value }}</span
      >
      <input
        type="text"
        matInput
        name="mobileNumber"
        formControlName="mobileNumber"
      />
      <mat-error
        *ngIf="
          phoneVerificationFormGroup.controls.mobileNumber.hasError('required')
        "
      >
        {{ 'auth.signup.mobile_number_error_required' | localePipe }}
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error
        *ngIf="
          phoneVerificationFormGroup.controls.mobileNumber.hasError('maxlength')
        "
      >
        {{ 'auth.signup.mobile_number_error_maxlength' | localePipe }}
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error
        *ngIf="
          phoneVerificationFormGroup.controls.mobileNumber.hasError('minlength')
        "
      >
        {{ 'auth.signup.mobile_number_error_maxlength' | localePipe }}
      </mat-error>

      <mat-error
        *ngIf="
          phoneVerificationFormGroup.controls.mobileNumber.hasError('pattern')
        "
      >
        {{ 'auth.signup.mobile_number_error_pattern' | localePipe }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div id="code-input">
    <button
      mat-flat-button
      color="accent"
      type="button"
      [disabled]="
        !phoneVerificationFormControls.countryTelephoneCode.valid ||
        !phoneVerificationFormControls.mobileNumber.valid ||
        !timerFinished
      "
      (click)="onSubmitNumber()"
      #submitNumberButton
    >
      <span *ngIf="countdownTimer === '0:00' || !countdownTimer"
        >{{ 'auth.signup.get_code' | localePipe }}</span
      >
      <span id="timer" *ngIf="countdownTimer !== '0:00'"
        >{{ countdownTimer }}</span
      >
    </button>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" id="sms-code__input">
      <input
        convertToEnglishNumeral
        placeholder="{{ 'auth.signup.sms_code' | localePipe }}"
        type="text"
        matInput
        name="code"
        formControlName="code"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <mat-error
    *ngIf="
      phoneVerification.controls.code.hasError('required') &&
      phoneVerification.controls.code.dirty
    "
  >
    {{ 'auth.signup.code_error_required' | localePipe }}
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="phoneVerification.controls.code.hasError('minlength')">
    {{ 'auth.signup.code_error_minlength' | localePipe }}
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="phoneVerification.controls.code.hasError('maxlength')">
    {{ 'auth.signup.code_error_maxlength' | localePipe }}
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="phoneVerification.controls.code.hasError('pattern')">
    {{ 'auth.signup.code_error_pattern' | localePipe }}
  </mat-error>
  <div *ngIf="errors && errors.code" class="error-feedback">
    <mat-error *ngFor="let error of errors.code"> {{ error }} </mat-error>
  </div>
```

And here's my `scss`:

```
    div.mobile-number__container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;

      dropdown-autocomplete-countries#countryTelephoneCode {
        width: 25%;
      }
      mat-form-field#mobileNumber {
        width: 72%;
        text-align: left;

        ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper,
        .mat-form-field-wrapper {
          ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
            direction: ltr;
            text-align: center;

            ::ng-deep input {
              letter-spacing: 5px;
            }

            ::placeholder {
              letter-spacing: normal;
            }
          }
        }

        mat-error {
          margin-top: 0;
        }
      }

      span {
        position: relative;
      }
    }

    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-suffix,
    .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-suffix {
      direction: ltr;
    }

    div#code-input {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      max-height: 51px;

      margin-top: 6px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;

      mat-form-field#sms-code__input {
        width: 72%;

        ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper,
        .mat-form-field-wrapper {
          ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
            direction: ltr;
            text-align: center;

            ::ng-deep input {
              letter-spacing: 18px;
            }

            ::placeholder {
              letter-spacing: normal;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      button {
        font-size: 0.8rem;

        margin: 0.7px 0;
        width: 25%;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
    }

    mat-error {
      min-height: 25px;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Here are the validator codes if it's any help:

```
this.phoneVerification = this.formBuilder.group({
  countryTelephoneCode: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(4),
      Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'),
    ],
  ],
  mobileNumber: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(15),
      Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'),
    ],
  ],
  code: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(CONSTANTS.PHONE_VERIFICATION_CODE_LENGTH),
      Validators.maxLength(CONSTANTS.PHONE_VERIFICATION_CODE_LENGTH),
      Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'),
    ],
  ],
});
```

Please let me know if there's any more information needed.

Comment: Can you show the Validator in .ts file?

Comment: @AntonioEsposito sure, I'll add it in a sec.

Comment: You have to display error one by one. 
View the example in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njxzay?file=src/app/form-field-overview-example.html

Comment: Check the name of the form also.

Comment: @AntonioEsposito okay but what about the time where for example both pattern and max length are incorrect? cause I have different validators for different regions and this kind of thing could happen.

Comment: One solution is display error one by one, for example, display first pattern error,
`phoneVerification.get('mobileNumber').hasError('maxlength') && !phoneVerification.get('mobileNumber').hasError('pattern')
`
[link] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njxzay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.html)